# MySQL PHP Query Select from Multiple Tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search script here, that needs to search multiple tables for a phrase/word using MySQL and PHP. The column `name` column that is being searched is all the same across tables. Any help would be appreciated and here is my code below:

```
<?php
    $filter = $_REQUEST['query'];
    mysql_connect($hostname,$username, $password) or die ("<script language='JavaScript'>alert('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.'),history.go(-1)</script>");
    mysql_select_db($dbname);
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT `name` FROM `voxmoviesfilestable`) a UNION (SELECT `name` FROM `voxadultfilestable`) b UNION (SELECT `name` FROM `voxmixesfilestable`) c UNION (SELECT `name` FROM `voxconcertsfilestable`) d UNION (SELECT `name` FROM `voxmp3filestable`) e UNION (SELECT `name` FROM `voxfilestable`) WHERE `name` REGEXP \''.$filter.'\' ORDER BY `name`;';
    $maxquery = 'SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM `voxmoviesfilestable`, `voxadultfilestable`, `voxmixesfilestable`, `voxconcertsfilestable`, `voxmp3filestable`, `voxfilestable` WHERE `name` REGEXP \''.$filter.'\';';

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ('Error accessing Database');
?>
```

Comment: Not a solution but you have a lot of syntax errors in `$query = 'SELECT * FROM WHERE REGEXP \''.$filter.'\' ORDER BY name;';`

Comment: any chance you can put all your data into **one** table?

Comment: Your first query isn't valid, there is no table name `SELECT * FROM WHERE REGEXP ...`. Is there any relation between these tables in the second query?

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited my code just before I pasted it. I have the latest code which still errors.

Comment: Maybe try this. Put a set of parentheses around the union selects. SELECT * FROM ( (SELECT `name` ... `voxfilestable`) ) WHERE `name` REGEXP...`

Answer (score 0):

The command "select ... from table1, table2, table3..." does not do what it appears you think it does. It does a massive join of every row of every table to every row of every other table. That is very bad. It looks like you want union. But, it isn't that easy as you must get the columns to look alike. It would look like:

```
select * from ((select id, name from table1) a union (select id, name from table2) b union ...) where regexp '$filter' order by name
```

NOTE: I added parenthesis around the union section about 12 hours after initially writing this.

The union will take time, but I believe it would be faster than querying each table separately in PHP.

Comment: I added parenthesis around the union section to ensure it does union first and then does the select outside the parenthesis. You will probably have to add a table alias to the union section by putting some letter or name after the closing parenthesis. It helps to know WHAT the error is. Use: if(!$result=mysql_query($query)) echo "$query\n".mysql_error()."\n";

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at it and get back to you.